# Header file containing 'const' included in multiple source files

Tags: c++, constants

Why **does not** a header file containing the definition for a `const` and included by multiple source files give a compilation error for `multiple definition` ?

**const_in_header_file.h**

```
const int num = 5;
//int x; //Error. Multiple defintion if included from multiple source files.
```

**const_in_header_file_func.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const_in_header_file.h"

using namespace std;

void func(void)
{
   cout << "num in func() = " << num << endl;
}
```

**const_in_header_file_main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const_in_header_file.h"

using namespace std;
extern void func(void);

int main()
{
   cout << "num in main() = " << num << endl;
   func();
}
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what the declaration looks like, including all relevant types?

Comment: @GregHewgill it's probably not at all needed :)

Comment: Probably indeed. It always helps to show actual code.

Comment: you will need to show the code to get a direct answer. in some cases and in some scopes, a definition in the header may exist legally and may be visible to multiple TUs, but there's a good amount of variation in C++ in this regard. in C++, there are multiple ways to fix this but again -- it depends on the type and the scope.

Comment: Sorry.My mistake. i actually meant `does not`. But could not update as network was down, before the answers came pouring in

Comment: @LinuxPenseur - I was unsure if you were having a compile error, a link error (or even, conceivably, both).  But I hope the answers you've received have helped, and I hope you're squared away now.  In the future, please be sure to 1) post code snippets, and 2) cut/paste the exact error message. Use guards and "extern" in your header; allocate the actual global in your main. Sincerely .. PSM

Answer (score 3):

In C++ global const is internal linkage. After combining header file with cpp files (header file will be "inserted" into cpp files where #include is), each compilation unit will be compiled to object file and then be linked together. Those functions and variables are internal linkage will not be seen by linker, which means your const global will not be seen at this stage. Even if you have two or more const in different object files, they are just hidden.
Only for those with external linkage functions and variables, linker will try to "assemble" the declaration with definition. 
For example:
If you have
`extern int a;` in one compilation unit (cpp with .h inserted);
linker will search for it's definition:
`int a;` (without external keyword).
If it found two, redefinition error appears.

For constant, they are just hidden to linker.

Answer (score 0):

Because if it really is a *definition* and not a *declaration*, then the compiler will create a (global) variable with the same name whenever it again and again encounters the definitoion - and then the linker doesn't know what to do with the multiple symbols with the same name in the resulting object code files.

Comment: Guess: Because `const` variables have internal linkage by default?

Comment: @CharlesBailey thanks! (but I gues you didn't downvote.) However, this should not be the case here - a multiple derinition error arises from duplicate symbols with external linkage. Or I am missing something about static linkage. Or OP's compiler's buggy.

Comment: A _compile_ error "multiple definitions" indicates that the object has been defined multiple times in a translation unit so the linkage of he object won't matter.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Really? Then try to link together two object files containing the same function.

Comment: I don't understand how your last comment relates to my comment. If my translation unit failed to compile I'm not going to have an object file to link in the first place which is why I said that the linkage is immaterial.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Yes, sorry. You're right (altough it certainly could have been a linker error, but I see your point).

Answer (score -1):

Probably because you wrote the header file ... but failed to include "[header guards"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

The lack of "header guards" would cause a compile error. Another possibility is that you failed to use "[extern](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/)".  This would cause a link error.

For example:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

extern int myglobal;

#endif
```

Please look at the above two links.  Please post a snippet of the code that's failing if adding a guard and/or using "extern" don't resolve the problem.

Comment: Exactly as you say: "The lack of header guards would cause a *compiler* error..." - but not a *linker* error, as OP wrote (because if compilation errors out, linkage doesn't even start).