# Linkage error for a header containing const variables and included in multiple files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, constants, linker-errors

I am writing code for testing in which I have a `TestUtil.h` which defines two constants and some functions. I have implementation of this header file as `TestUtil.cpp` and there is third file `ActualTests.cpp` in which I am writing the actual tests. The `TestUtil.h` and `TestUtil.cpp` are just helper files to write concise tests.

I am having nested namespaces and the `TestUtil.h` looks like this:

```
namespace SNMPSubAgentTesting {

  namespace MibDataReaderTesting {

     const wchar_t* TEST_MUTEX_NAME = L"TestMutex";

     const wchar_t* TEST_MEMORY_NAME = L"TestMemory";

   //some functions 
   } 
}
```

In the implementation `TestUtil.cpp` I include the above header file and give implementations:

```
#include "TestUtil.h"

 namespace SNMPSubAgentTesting {

  namespace MibDataReaderTesting {
     //implementations
  }
}
```

In the third file `ActualTests.cpp` I again include the `TestUtil.h` in order to use the util functions:

```
#include "TestUtil.h"

 namespace SNMPSubAgentTesting {

  namespace MibDataReaderTesting {

     //Test class and tests
  }
}
```

The compiler gives a linkage error and says that the two `const` variables in `TestUtil.h` are already defined in `TestUtil.cpp` and hence `ActualTests.cpp` cannot be compiled. Since `const` variables are internally linked and we can include the header containing `const` variables in multiple files without linking errors, why does it not link in my case? Is it because of nested namespaces?

**EDIT: I am using the Microsoft Unit Test framework for testing.
The const variables are in MibDataReaderTesting namespace and not in global namespace.**

**I have header files in my source code which are included in multiple files and have const variables in them. No error in this case but for the testing case it gives error. Only difference b/w source and test code is testing framework and nested namespaces**

Comment: you're defining objects in global namespace in your header. They will be defined as-such in whatever translation unit pulls them in. That they are `const` is irrelevant. One proper solution is to `extern` them in the header *without* specified initial values, then put their actual definitions in *one* translation unit with initial (and since they're const, permanent) values.

Comment: @WhozCraig But names declared at namespace scope should have internal linkage if they are "... non-volatile non-template (since C++14) non-inline (since C++17) non-exported (since C++20) **const-qualified variables** (including constexpr) that aren't declared `extern` and aren't previously declared to have external linkage" (emphasis mine). These variables are in namespace scope, are const-qualified, and haven't been declared `extern` and aren't previously declared to have external linkage. (Quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage).

Comment: @WhozCraig but the variables are defined inside the `MibDataReaderTesting` namespace. How are they in global namespace?

Comment: What's the compiler and what version of C++ are you compiling against?

Comment: @MahanGM It is Visual C++ in Visual studio with latest Windows SDK

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude has it been this way since inception (I see all the language for the specific cases), but according to the cppr you cited, const qualified within namespaces have no such qualifications. So.. it's been that way since at least c++98 ? news to me, because it's always been my experience, at least with msvc toolchains, that this doesn't work, and one has to jockey extern decls. now I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @NavjotSingh misappropriation of term on my part. I apologize for that. According to SPD, this should work for you, and I certainly take his word on it (he's forgotten more about this language than I'll probably ever know). I've used VC toolchains for decades, and this has *always* been, for me at least, the case where I had to jockey extern decls as I described, even in namespaces. Now I'm curious and want to fend this in clang and my latest vc toolchain (which is *supposed* to be language compatible to 14). I'm sure what I suggested will work, but I think you're right; you shouldn't have to.

Comment: @WhozCraig As SPD quoted, it's a feature since C++20. That's just new.

Comment: @MahanGM then it's terribly worded on cppr, as it infers that exports are the C++20 feature being referenced, and the const-qualified vars are not hindered/limited to *any* specific language level, as the prior qualifiers were.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's my take. I don't know what people do these days :)

Comment: I have other header files in same project that are included at multiple places and have `const` in them and are not generating error. This is only happening for my testing code.

Comment: @NavjotSingh it your test project source that is puking on this? not the rest of your regular source and their projects ? Interesting...

Comment: @NavjotSingh As far as I know, in order to have variables in header files, you need to make them either static, inline or extern. I have tested your code under C++98, C++14 and C++17 and all of them give the same error and the reason for that is you can have multiple declarations but only one definition,

Comment: @MahanGM Well, then it should give error at some other places as well but it doesn't. My guess is that I am using the same namespaces in `TestUtil.cpp` and `ActualTests.cpp`. I will try changing namespaces and then discuss

Comment: @WhozCraig To be honest, in my own experience I have never had this work for me either. cppreference.com is usually accurate so I don't doubt it, but a glance through the specification might be needed to confirm it. There might be some finer point that I missed.

Comment: Guys have a look at this question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980806/header-file-containing-const-included-in-multiple-source-files

Comment: @NavjotSingh I tested the code again, it works without a pointer type. I don't know what's the deal with having pointers, maybe the compilation is different, but that's the reason.

Comment: @MahanGM Something is really wierd. Because I am very sure that in my source code part I have included header in multiple files and these header have `const` pointers variables. Linker doesn't cry there but cries when i do in test code.

Comment: @MahanGM "Pointers"! That's the key here! Thanks for pointing (no pun intended) it out. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this internal linkage reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage) `const` qualified names have internal linkage.

The problem is that your names are *not* `const` qualified. The `const` is for the data the pointers are pointing to, not for the variables themselves.

You need to add a `const` in the correct place:

```
const wchar_t* const TEST_MUTEX_NAME = L"TestMutex";
//             ^^^^^
// Make TEST_MUTEX_NAME itself constant
```

Comment: Well this is crazy. I take your word but I still don't get linkage errors in other parts of code where I did the same thing.

Comment: @NavjotSingh Do you have both low-level and top-level consts for them as well?

Comment: @MahanGM the source code is just like as in my question. Only with the outer `const`. Only linker knows why it lets me free at one place and not at other. However the solution from SPD works.

Comment: @NavjotSingh That's the point. You either don't have pointer types or if you have, they have a top-level const. You'll figure it out once you examine it more.

Comment: @MahanGM one observation that matches with yours. In the source I am including multiple time the header file which has const variables which are not pointers. You also found that. I think this applies only to pointers.Lesson learnt

Comment: @NavjotSingh The reason is explained. First (low-level) const is for the variable, second (top-level) const is for the pointer. By making the pointer const, compiler can ensure that this variable would never change in anyway, so it can be eligible for the internal linkage and all that jazz.

Comment: @NavjotSingh It't nothing special with pointers, it's just that the placement of the `const` that is relevant. `const char* p = "foo";` defines `p` as a "pointer to `char` that is `const`" and is equivalent to `char const* p = "foo;"` where `p` is a "pointer to a `const` `char`". When you write `const char* const p = "foo";`then you say that "`p` is a `const` pointer to a `char` that is `const`". It's the "`const` pointer" that is relevant for pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Clears all doubts. Thanks